# How to implements whatsapp share button in website

Tags: javascript, php, api

Im building a website in php , i would like to implement whatsapp share button in it .I searched the internet for  a while but couldn't find anything can any one explain how it works and how can i implement

Thanks in advance

Comment: whatapp share only works when you are using mobile device,

Comment: Not anymore. Try https://wa.me/?text=Some+Text

Answer (score 31):

**UPDATE**

A simplified version of the below URL is, here number and text are optional

https://wa.me/91XXXXXXXXXX?text=urlencodedtext

```
<a href="https://wa.me/91XXXXXXXXXX?text=urlencodedtext" target="_blank">WA</a>
```

---

This might help you

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=91XXXXXXXXXX&text=urlencodedtext" target="_blank">WA</a>
```

phone and text parameters are not mandatory

this works in the mobile browser and pc browser, in pc this will open https://web.whatsapp.com/

I think this might be a better solution.

Comment: This will require a Phone no to work I guess

Comment: no it is optional

Answer (score 14):

**Please note that this only works with mobile devices and mobile browsers**

use this to share in whatsapp,
text= The text to share / link / or anything; if you are using url, dont forget to encode it

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

Comment: is there any way to make it work in whatsapp web

Comment: @FaizalHussain you can either add two different html tags and make it toggle based on viewport. Or you can manage its behavior with Javascript.

Comment: href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=The text to share!" @FaizalHussain