# How to share WhatsApp on WhatsApp web on desktop and WhatsApp app on phone

Tags: html, whatsapp

I'm trying to implement a button that shares the current page on WhatsApp, there's no issue with using the link on phone but on desktop I can't send it to WhatsApp web or open WhatsApp web if it's not opened yet.

I was searching for long on Stack Overflow and other webpages as well on documentation, which I can't find (I only face Android documentation but not web documentation for it).

I referred to https://api.whatsapp.com nut no info can be found here.
No info about WhatsApp share API here:
https://developers.facebook.com/ neither on resuts from search share WhatsApp or sharing WhatsApp.

My approach is this line as I said someone posting here:
[How to implements whatsapp share button in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712618/how-to-implements-whatsapp-share-button-in-website)

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=this%20was%20amazing%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.es%2F" target="_blank">Share to whatsapp</a>
```

I bet that this function was moved to WhatsApp for business, are it?

OK I found this browsing on latest Google's result pages:

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=this%20was%20amazing%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.es%2F" target="_blank">share to whatsapp web</a>
```

This does not answer the question at all as it's supposed to work as a single button with detect and fallback (api.whatsapp I mean), but it can be a nice approach to show and hide one of these two options if the client is on desktop or in mobile.

If someone knows a different approach it could be nice.

Another issue/bug with this approach is that on desktop, it opens always a new web.whatsapp.com tab even if you've it opened before.

Comment: this works on desktop browser https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=12234234&text=text

Comment: this works on mobile browser https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5354345&text=text

Comment: Can we use api.whatsapp to share a attachment . like we have send?text=